# Dialog-flow Chat bot using MySQL

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am developing a Chat bot using Dialog-flow which will be based on a database that I am preferring to use MySQL. The Chat bot will send the answers on the basis of DB after querying the data.

I have created a basic chat bot with a small Database.

What should I do to develop a communication link between MySQL and the Dialog-flow or is there any Database that I can use? Help me, please.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review [ask] to help us help you. A good [mcve] is also a good thing. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

To communicate with your database from a Dialogflow agent, you will need to use [fulfillment](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment).

Dialogflow has a [fulfillment library for Node.js](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/node-libraries) that you can use to start building your fulfillment code. You can see the [Dialogflow GitHub](https://github.com/dialogflow/resources) for many samples of fulfillment code.

If you are using Node.js to build your fulfillment, you can integrate it with MySQL via a Node.js MySQL client such as [mysqljs/mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql).

Comment: Here is a video tutorial on this topic https://youtu.be/v7k5vckSzNo