# How to fetch data from MySQL database into Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have created a chatbot using DialogFlow as a platform. I have 2 questions in it, 1) How can I fetch data from MySQL into DialogFlow? and if so 2) How can I integrate the created chatbot with my android app?

Comment: “This is called Invariance and Covariance. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.”

Comment: possible duplicate of => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52622676/dialog-flow-chat-bot-using-mysql